# change ${basedir} to reference desktop in NLog.config

Tags: xml, config, desktop, nlog

I need to find a way to reference a directory on the desktop in the NLog.config file.
Currently the NLog target is set to:

```
fileName="${basedir}/Daily Logs/TGTLogFile${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.txt"
```

I need it to point to `...Desktop/Daily Logs/TGTLogFile${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.txt`

It can't be a static string referencing my user folder, as this application is used on multiple computers.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *special folder* layout renderer:

use it instead of `${basedir}`:

```
fileName="${specialfolder:folder=DesktopDirectory}/Daily Logs/TGTLogFile${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.txt"
```

See [docs of ${specialfolder}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer) and [list of all renderers](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers)

Comment: You are a beautiful person! Works fantastically well. Thank you
(half a day of Googling got me nowhere. You are officially better than Google.)

Comment: Thanks! I hope that the searchable list (https://nlog-project.org/config) will help you finding stuff :)